# How to patch for CVE-2014-6271 & CVE-2014-7169?

Tags: linux, centos, bash, centos6, opensuse

CVE-2014-6271 & CVE-2014-7169 is a bash related bug that reported at 24-Sep-2014. 
http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-6271
https://securityblog.redhat.com/2014/09/24/bash-specially-crafted-environment-variables-code-injection-attack/

I'm using openSUSE 11.0 (bash version: bash-3.2-112.1) and asked to patch for CVE-2014-6271 & CVE-2014-7169, I tried YaST however it didn't work.  I would like to ask any rpm could help to patch this bug?

I have tried yum update on CentOS 6.4 too, but after update the bug still exist, is there any official announce for CentOS 6.4 patch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

OpenSUSE 11.0 is [out of support](https://en.opensuse.org/Lifetime) for 4 years. Update this thing to a supported OS.

Answer (score 2):

As SvW already covered the SuSE part, here is the answer for CentOS:
Only the latest CentOS minor versions get patches -- as always.
Update to CentOS 6.5. There won't be patches for 6.4.

Patches for CentOS 6.5 are already released.

Comment: The CentOS 6.5 rpm works fine on CentOS 6.4 though

Comment: Thanks!  Can I update from 6.4 to 6.5 using yum?